# Data type for storing object pair other than Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

What would be the best data type for storing non-unique pairs of objects? I cannot use Dictionary because the key has to be unique. I could create an object with the two data types as properties and store them in a list, but that wouldn't be flexible enough to accommodate the different data type pairs. Something almost like Dictionary but non-unique. A build-in solution from .NET would be even better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>` would work best here.

- [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `List<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>`. `Dictionary` class uses `KeyValuePair` too.